Qt for MAC: Remove focus from textfield when clicking on a checkbox
In Mac by default it seems like clicking on a checkbox does not cause a textfield in the same window to lose focus (in windows this works by default).
How can I ensure Mac has the same behavour as Windows?
I have the following code for testing purpose:
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QCheckBox>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
, ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    //ui->setupUi(this);
    QWidget* pCentral = new QWidget(this);
    setCentralWidget(pCentral);
    pCentral->setLayout(new QVBoxLayout());

    QTextEdit* pText = new QTextEdit();
    pCentral->layout()->addWidget(pText);

    QCheckBox* pCheck = new QCheckBox();
    pCheck->setText("test checkbox");
    pCentral->layout()->addWidget(pCheck);
}

PS:
I know I can use setFocusPolicy to explicitly change the focus behavior of widgets like this, for example.:
pCheck->setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);

Apparently, the click focus is not enabled for checkboxes on Mac. But, is it possible to enable strong focus for all widgets, like checkboxes, by default? I would like to avoid having to set it for every widget separately ...
Update:
I worked out a brute force solution by going through all checkboxes in the showEvent and adjust their focus policy:
for (QCheckBox* pCheck : this->findChildren<QCheckBox*>())
    pCheck->setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);

But if there is a more elegant solution I would love to hear it.

Are you sure you want to diverge from the macOS focus conventions here? The windows behavior would be just as alien to macOS users..

Well it's the set guideline for this feature. I don't have a say in the matter ...

@Benjamin If that's a requirement, then there's little you can do: either programmatically force the focus policy, or use subclasses for those check boxes. Note that doing that on showEvent(), while not completely wrong, is not really effective: for instance, it'll be done every time the window is restored after minimizing, and if the widget tree is big, that could become an unnecessary issue. Possible alternatives: 1. if the UI is static, then just do that in the constructor; 2. if it's dynamic, then override childEvent() and check for polished() events (possibly calling a specific »

» function activated by a persistent single shot QTimer that is restarted for every polished() child event; 3. create a QObject filter and install it as event filter of the QApplication, checking for MouseButtonPress events (note that this wouldn't address the tab-navigation issue, which may still be important to some users even nowadays). Finally, it may be important to know why that requirement is needed: while consistent behavior across different systems is important, consistent behavior within a specific OS is also as important, and sometimes even more. If the program is aimed to »

» users that commonly use that program on different systems, then it may be acceptable, but that's a rare situation. Most of the time, an user that commonly works with different systems is also used to their different behavior; in fact, they may find it quite annoying to see that the UI reacts in an OS-inconsistent way (I know I would). If, instead, that requirement is just because "somebody" wants the UI to work in the same way everywhere, even for people that always uses one system and no matter the established OS conventions, then I'd say that it's a dumb, arrogant and ignorant request.

@musicamante great answer! Make it a proper answer so others can find it?

@Botje Unfortunately I'm not able to write C++ (I use Qt from Python), so if I write an answer I won't be able to provide any example code. If that still satisfies you, I'll write it as a text only answer, at least adding more details about what written above.

The code for each of your scenarios would be trivial, but the insight applies generally.

First of all, it should be noted that the known and accepted behavior of a specific OS should always be respected. That is most important especially for established systems like Windows and macOS, which have well established standards that their users expect.
Those aspects should always be respected, even while writing a cross-platform program: unless that program is intended for users that are known to be using the same program on different platforms, proper UX management should follow the accepted standard of each specific system, especially if the appearance follows those standards too (which is the default of a QApplication, unless its style is overridden): if, for instance, macOS users see a "macOS-like" program, they will expect it to behave like any other standard macOS program, including aspects like focus behavior.
Yet, overriding that may a requirement out of our control, and we have to accept that, meaning that we need to ignore the behavior most users will give for granted.
While the concept of altering the focusPolicy of the widgets remains, there are many possible ways to do it, each one with their pros and cons.
Applying the policy in the main window constructor
This only works for "static" UIs, where their content is created using Designer or by code in the constructor, and no children are ever added (dialog windows included).
It's quite simple and effective: just use [findChildren()] approach you proposed in the question, but always after calling setupUi() or after adding any other widget.
The drawback is that if any new checkbox is added afterwards you need to ensure that you manually set the policy.
Note that you should ensure that you only set the proper flag without resetting any others. The proper syntax would be the following:
for (QCheckBox* pCheck : this->findChildren<QCheckBox*>())
    pCheck->setFocusPolicy(pCheck->focusPolicy() | Qt::ClickFocus);

I'm no C++ dev, I'm not 100% sure about the above syntax, but the concept should be clear anyway.
Use a subclass
This is quite obvious: create a QCheckBox subclass and automatically set the focus policy no matter what. The drawback of that is that you must always use that subclass for checkboxes, meaning that if you use a Designer made UI you must also use promoted widgets for each check box (unless you remember to manually set the policy in Designer).
Set the policy when shown/created
Your proposal of overriding showEvent() may work for simple cases, but you also have to remember that a QEvent::Show may be triggered in many cases: not only when the widget is shown the first time, but also when it's shown again after being hidden (eg: a page in QTabWidget), or when the window is restored after being minimized or a virtual desktop switch. This means that in each one of those occasions you may iterate through the whole widget tree, possibly pointlessly, as the focus policies have already been set.
Also, if a new child is added (eg: a container with its own QCheckBoxes) while the parent widget/window is already visible, no focus policy change will be done.
Installing an event filter on the QApplication
This is probably the safest method: create a custom QObject subclass that acts as an application-wide event filter, and watch for QChildEvents.
Here is some "python-like pseudo code":
class CheckBoxMonitor(QObject):
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if (
            event.type() == <watched-child-event-type>
            and <condition matching QCheckBox>
        ):
            set focus policy on the event.child()

        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)

monitor = CheckBoxMonitor()

QApplication.instance().installEventFilter(monitor)

Now, here's the catch: the filter will be triggered on any event type, and there are two possible event types we may watch, QEvent::ChildAdded and QEvent::ChildPolished.
The former is the most promising, but has a fundamental flaw; widgets created with a parent in their constructors (the default for widgets created in Designer) will cause a ChildAdded event at the very beginning of their construction, and at that point they are barely initialized: not only we won't get the widget type, the event.child() won't even be a QWidget at all, but just a plain QObject. This means that we cannot check the actual object type (because it hasn't been fully constructed yet), therefore the only way we have is to check against the object's metaObject and eventually use setProperty('focusPolicy', Qt.StrongFocus) if the meta object className() is "QCheckBox".
The reason for using setProperty() instead of setFocusPolicy() is obvious: the object is still a QObject, not yet a QWidget, therefore it has no setFocusPolicy() member. Note, though, that this prevents any default focus policy possibly set for the widget. It may be acceptable for this specific case, but it may be not for other widget types: since the object does not have an actual focus policy property set, we cannot try to OR it.
Another issue with this is that the class will be specific, so if you're using subclasses you also need to recursively check the superClass() of the meta object until it's acceptable (eg: until the "QWidget" className() is found).
The ChildPolished alternative is slightly better: it's always called at least once when the child widget shown the first time, or its size hint functions need to query the style in order to provide a proper response.
This means that, when the event is triggered, the widget is already initialized, so we can easily check its type/inheritance and call setFocusPolicy().
This is not without issues, though: any style change (including setting style sheets at runtime) will trigger related events for all widgets involved by the change, which would potentially delay the behavior even further, and probably for nothing if the focus policy of all widgets have been already set.
Considering that we're setting the event filter on the whole application, this means that the override will be called for any event, and eventually checked against any child (including non widgets).
If the program is relatively complex and may react to many frequent events, this approach can add a relatively significant overhead, especially considering that it's only for something that is potentially required only once for every new widget.
Final considerations
As said in the premise, you should carefully consider if this requirement is really needed. Some years have passed since I've used an apple device and I sincerely didn't recall about this aspect, but if that's really the expected behavior of that OS you should probably follow it, and eventually point out the UX aspects pointed above, which should never be underestimated (I know for a fact that many designers/head office/managers tend to fixate on their own beliefs, completely disregarding real user expectations and habits).
Also consider that if the focus change of the text field is the only primary requirement (and not that of the generic check box behavior), specific implementation for such cases only should be done, instead of trying any of the solutions above.
